# Spark Streaming : number of executor vs Custom Receiver

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Why Spark with one worker node and four executors, each with one core cannot able to process **Custom Receiver** ??

What are the reason for not processing incoming data via Custom Receiver, if the executor is having a single core in Spark Streaming ?

I am running Spark on Standalone mode. I am getting data in Custom receivers in **Spark Streaming** app. My laptop is having 4 cores.

master="spark://lappi:7077"

$spark_path/bin/spark-submit --executor-cores 1 --total-executor-cores 4 \
  --class "my.class.path.App" \
  --master  $master

Comment: The question is not clear enough, please share the exact code, method used to run it and logs.

Answer (score 4):

You indicate that your (1) executor should have 1 core reserved for Spark, which means you use 1 of your 4 cores. The parameter `total-executor-cores` is never limiting since it limits the total amount of cores on your cluster reserved for Spark, which is, per your previous setting, 1.

The Receiver consumes one thread for consuming data out of your one available, which means you have no core left to process data. All of this is explained in the doc:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#input-dstreams-and-receivers

You want to bump that `executor-cores` parameter to 4.

Comment: If I specify,  **$spark_path/bin/spark-submit --executor-cores 4 --total-executor-cores 4** , then spark will create  single executor with all 4 cores. It means, in this case also, Spark will not able to process incoming data stream of 4 custom receivers.

Comment: Why o earth would you have 4 custom receivers ? It's one receiver per DStream, not one receiver per core.

Comment: I followed your instructions.